# configure paperclip to generate styles when they are requested

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, carrierwave

I need a user to upload an original file and process that into a thumbnail (paperclip's got this - check).

Then I would like to be able to retrieve different styles for that attachment, but I do not need to store those different styles on disk anywhere. I would prefer they are generated during the request.

The reason for that is that these styles are single-use.  So, paperclip becomes a glorified one-time-use image resiszer.  I'd prefer not to incur the S3 cost if I don't have to.

Wondering if there'a way to do this out of the box.  Or, maybe carrierwave supports something like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the [Refile](https://github.com/refile/refile) library supports it. Refile is basically a modern version of the Carrierwave, written by the same author.

You can read more about the on-the-fly processing here:
https://github.com/refile/refile#processing